# Failing to pass the test of XHR request using Cypress

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress

Hi people I am new to cypress and I am trying to pass the XHR test but I am failing.
What am I doing wrong?

Here are my:

```
Request URL: http://example.com/api/customer
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
```

Here is my route where my app goes after successful Request:

```
http://example.com/main/dasboard
```

Here is my Cypress test:

```
it.only("Waiting for server response", () => {
    cy.server();
    cy.route("POST", "**/api/customer").as("dataGetFirst");
    cy.wait("@dataGetFirst").its("status").should("be", 200);
  });
```

On my understanding I have to use the request ending api/customer or I need to use /main/dashboard ?? I also tried to just /customer but test is failing with this error:

```
Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: dataGetFirst. No request ever occurred.
```

UPDATE:

user Alapan Das suggested me to run this code:

```
it.only("Waiting for server response", () => {
  cy.request({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://example.com/api/customer",
    failOnStatusCode: false
  }).then((resp) => {
    expect(resp.status).to.eq(200);
  });
});
```

And my test passed, it appears that somehow my method is accepting GET method instead of POST and I will accept it as a solution for my question.

Please note, that here to describe my problem I am using a `http://example.com/api/customer` as an example which is not my real test case

Comment: Can you try this. This will check your redirection: `cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com/api/customer',
    followRedirect: false // turn off following redirects
  })
  .then((resp) => {
    // redirect status code is 302
    expect(resp.status).to.eq(302)
    expect(resp.redirectedToUrl).to.eq('http://example.com/main/dasboard')
  })`

Comment: What is redirect status code 302??

Comment: since your URL is redirecting to another URL that is why the 302. You can try with 200 as well, as I don't know what HTTP status code your application responds on redirection. Also, The above code will not redirect you but will only check the redirection. In case if you want to redirect to `http://example.com/main/dasboard` just use `followRedirect: true`

Comment: I tried both, it give a 404 error now

Comment: My assumption is it doesn't have any authentication and also you are using the entire URL instead of a partial URL and also the same endpoint is working when you hit it via Postman (or similar tool), and the request endpoint doesn't need a request body. Can you just try this then - `cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com/api/customer',
  })
  .then((resp) => {
    expect(resp.status).to.eq(200)
  })`

Comment: this is what I get: The response we received from your web server was:

  > 405: Method Not Allowed

This was considered a failure because the status code was not 2xx or 3xx.

If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: failOnStatusCode: false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by using [cy.request()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Syntax):

```
cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://example.com/api/customer',
    failOnStatus: false
}).then((resp) => {
    expect(resp.status).to.eq(200)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a different approach now, but to address your initial issue I believe your problem was that you never initiated the request.

The request must be initiated after the cy.route() and before the cy.wait().

It works like this:

```
it.only("Waiting for server response", () => {
    cy.server();
    cy.route("POST", "**/api/customer").as("dataGetFirst");
    // Do something here to trigger the request!
    cy.wait("@dataGetFirst").its("status").should("be", 200);
  });
```

And if you upgrade to the latest version of Cypress you'll want to use cy.intercept() instead:

```
it.only("Waiting for server response", () => {
    cy.intercept("POST", "**/api/customer").as("dataGetFirst");
    // Do something here to trigger the request!
    cy.wait("@dataGetFirst").its("status").should("be", 200);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Server and routes are depricated, I have had the same problem, here is the solution:

```
  cy.intercept(
    {
    method:'GET',
    url:'/api/channels/e5932cce
    }).as('loginLoaded')
 
  cy.get("@loginLoaded").then((xhr) => {
    cy.wait('@loginLoaded').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200)
    })
```